# How can i find length property of arguments?

Tags: javascript, arguments

```js
const add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(add));
```

In this code, why can't I find length property of arguments object?

Comment: Have you tried `arguments.length`??

Comment: And note that arguments are not properties of the function object. The number of arguments passed to a function on a particular function call can be determined *inside* the function, not outside.

Comment: The ["length of a function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) is how many parameters it _defines_. Obviously it makes no sense for the number it's _called with_ to be a property of the function, because that depends call-by-call on how many it's called with on each specific invocation.